How to connect supabase with the new version of nuxt
I get the following error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'http://localhost:3001/_nuxt/@fs/home/bobak/codehub/nuxt-mastering/node_modules/.pnpm/@supabase+postgrest-js@1.16.3/node_modules/@supabase/postgrest-js/dist/cjs/index.js?v=25186966' doesn't provide an export named: 'default'
the following is the error message:
this is my configurations for supabase:
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // compatibilityDate: '2024-04-03',
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/supabase','@nuxt/ui', '@nuxtjs/google-fonts',],
  
  googleFonts: {
    families: {
      Poppins: [400, 500, 700]
    }
  },
  supabase: {
    redirectOptions: {
      login: 'auth/login',
      callback: '',
      exclude: ['/auth/*']
    }
  },
  app: {
    head: {
      title: 'Bobak News'
    }
  }
})

